# How to resize /usr and /root directories on Ubuntu via terminal?

Tags: partitioning, resize

The way to resize via terminal on Ubuntu, is little complicate.

So, would like to learn which are these commands for resizing this directories (/usr & /root) and how to do it.

Comment: You are referring to partitions?

Comment: Yes, but via terminal look the title..

Comment: to @Videonauth: Is not duplicate because the answers at quesion: How to resize partitions? aren't refered to terminal. Also, do not solve my problem.

Comment: you won't like this, but by far the easiest way is to take a full backup, reinstall, and restore the backup. You have to take the full backup anyway in case the resizing fails, might as well put it to good use.

Comment: why did you create a separate root partition in the first place? The reasons for doing this have not existed in at least twenty years.

Comment: @JayEye: I did it to experiment myself with Linux.

Comment: Experimentation good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't resize partitions while there are mounted. This said you can extend them if they are using lvm.

If you are not using lvm, best is to boot on a livecd or usb and use gparted or parted tool if you prefer the command line.

By the way, nowadays the usual fashion to partition system is /, /home, swap.
/ at 20G is enough for most of people, swap the size of RAM and everything else in /home.